# Set color to struct name on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change name of struct color, but "*textmate scope*" this word shows how "*source.go*"
How I can chnage name struct color in golang VSCode

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This extension fix the problem[image: img]